# Navigation In react native android/ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native, visual-studio-code, navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiMGB.png)

I am facing this error I don't know what might be the reason as I am new in react native I am exporting all possible packages modules and libraries but still could resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmFgU.png)

Answer (score 0):

propably wrong package name

"react-navigation-stack" not to be confused with package "@react-navigation/stack"

[installation guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

on your second screenshot i see you are using a package that has been removed from react-native. In order to install it, take a look at community packages. to find out the corresponding package name google the following:

react native community "NAME-OF-THE-PACKAGE"

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps

1. First of all install React Navigation

npm: `npm install @react-navigation/native`
or
yarn: `yarn add @react-navigation/native`

2. React Navigation works on react-native-screens so install this

npm: `npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`
or
yarn: `yarn add react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`

3. then install stack navigation

npm: `npm install @react-navigation/stack`
or
yarn: `yarn add @react-navigation/stack`

4. after that, You also need to install react-native-gesture-handler.

npm: `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`
or
yarn: `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler`

5. after that, You also need to install react-native-masked-view/masked-view if you want to use different navigation animation i recommend you to install this even if you don't want to use animations.

npm: `npm install @react-native-masked-view/masked-view`
or
yarn: `yarn add @react-native-masked-view/masked-view`

references:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator

Comment: info Connecting to the development server...
8081
info Starting the app on "17b056e1"...

Comment: Still im facing this i've added all these packages

Comment: ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.

Comment: try Closing your metro bundler and re-run the app again